# displace modifier generator unexpected rhombus

Tags: rendering

I generated terrain from height map using the *Displace* modifier.  Everything is fine, but when i switch to *Wireframe View*, I find some 'rhombus', and if observed carefully there are ugly effects in solid view. Has anyone encountered this situation?

[image]

[image]

[image: 2]

[image: EFFECT]

Comment: What is your pre-displace mesh, what is your post displace mesh, what is the displacement.  It looks like you're showing pre-displace mesh in 2nd pic, in which case, no, the displace is not making the rhombus.  Something earlier than the displace (incl maybe your edits) is making the rhombus.